# Creating a custom list to sharepoint using client object model

Tags: list, custom-list

I am having problems creating a custom list from the client object model.

I need my list to have two columns - "Title" and "CustomID", both able to store a single line of text. I seem to be failing at finding any specific examples relating to my problem.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link and see if it can help you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg701783.aspx#ProfSPBrandUserIfaceDesign_Ch13_CommonListOperations

Comment: No problem, my pleasure.